# Magento 1.9.3 Load Different Layered Navigation Filter Selection

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

We have layered navigation items like **Window Width**, **Window Height** etc.

Upon Selecting **Door Height**, Magento bring the results of `Window Width` and also show `"Window Width"` instead of `"Window Height"` in Shop By area.

We have checked that `$filterItem->getFilter()->getRequestVar()` in `Catalog/Model/Layer` also show `"Window Width"` instead of `"Window Height"` attribute.

This is only with `Window Height` attribute. However all other filters are working perfectly.